# Does type checking occur after compiling typescript file?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm making a simple web server using nest.js!

This is my code in a controller file.

```
  @Delete('users/:id/courses/:course_id')
  deleteUserCourses(
    @Param() { id, course_id }: { id: number; course_id: string },
  ) {
    return this.usersService.deleteUserCourses(id, course_id);
  }
```

When I sent a delete request message toward "/users/123/courses/math",

I expected a type error on variable *id*, because *id* and *course_id* have string type.

However, I didn't get any error or warning.

Is that because the compiled typescript file does not check variable types in runtime?

Or there are any other reasons that type checking does not occur?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding validation in runtime you should use dto objects and validation technic that nestjs is providing via `class-validator` package. Read more about it [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, TS doesn't check types in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Typechecking is done at **compile time**.

The runtime will run plain JS, that's what all the transpilers do: transform your TS code files to JS files.